# Add addUser along side findBy

Tags: java, spring

I have a custom `AccountRepository` interface that extends `JpaRepository`:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.boot.cut_costs.config.security.CustomUserDetails;

public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomUserDetails, String>{
    public CustomUserDetails findByUsername(String username);
}
```

How can I add another method `addUser(String username, String password)` to use this AccountRepository to add new user to my database ? I want to make sure that there's no duplicate username in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `CrudRepository` instead of `JpaRepository`.

`CrudRepository` is subclass of `JpaRepository` which provides all methods for CRUD like save, delete etc.

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<CustomUserDetails, String>{
    public CustomUserDetails findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Then in your service you would be able to use:

```
accountRepository.save(newUser);
```

If you want to avoid having duplicate username, you can set `unique` constain on database column.

If you generate your database from java entities, you could annotate username field like this:

```
@Column(unique=true)
String username;
```

You can also provide your own [implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations):

```
class AccountRepositoryImpl implements AccountRepository { //AccountRepository is extending CrudRepository

  public void addUser(User user) {
      if(!exists(user.getId())){ //methods exists and save come from CrudRepository
           save(user);
      } else {
          //handle error
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a more detailed implementation for it ? instead of having it as an interface and working with annotations to specify implementation details.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer, hope it is something you're looking for.

Comment: So, I would have one interface (which would have `findBy`) and one implementation for that interface which would have `addUser` ? and both would be taken into account as beans for the security ?